# Splitting merged page numbers from a pdf file

Tags: pdf, pdflatex

I'm trying to print out lecture slides from a pdf file, but I'm having trouble with the page numbers. This is the lecture slide:

https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece486/documents/Fa14Slides/lec03.pdf

Basically, each page number is associated with multiple slides (i.e. the first 3 slides is considered to be page 1, slides 4-14 is considered to be page 2). I'm trying print out the 'final' slides in each page.

I printed specific pages (e.g. 3, 14, 19, 25, 29...), but apparently this prints out the actual pages, not the slides itself.

Is there a way to get around this issue other than going for pressing 'prt sc' then pasting the slides that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF viewer in Firefox does get the pages correctly. Printing with it prints the correct page for me on Linux. Should work the same way on Windows and Mac OSx too.

I used 4"x6" postcard format in paysage mode to print. That lets only one slide per page.

Also, I just tried to print with 8.5x11" letter size in paysage mode and a print scale of 200% and it is ok, just printing one slide per page as it should.

Comment: It seems that if your paper is too large and can contain many slides, it prints them on the same page. So zooming on the print will prevent that.